# Getting Ractive data by, say, "id", rather than by the object index

Tags: ractivejs

Say my Ractive data looks like this:

```
items: [
  { id: 16, name: "thingy" },
  { id: 23, name: "other thingy"}
]
```

I know I can do this to get the first item:

```
ractive.get('items.0')
```

But how do I get (or delete, or update, for that matter) the item who's id is 23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly a javascript issue, but you could put methods on your ractive instance or on the prototype generally. Assuming your array was not too large and using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), you could do something like:

```
Ractive.prototype.getIndexById = function(keypath, id){
    this.get(keypath).findIndex(function(each){
        return each.id === id;
    });
}

Ractive.prototype.getById = function(keypath, id){
    return this.get(keypath).find(function(each){
        return each.id === id;
    });
}

Ractive.prototype.delete = function(keypath, id){
    return this.splice(keypath, this.getIndexById(id), 1);
}

Ractive.prototype.update = function(keypath, id, data){
    return this.set(keypath + '.' + this.getIndexById(id), data);
}
```

But if you're just trying to get a handle an item from which an action occurred, you should use the context:

```
{{#items:i}}
<li on-click='selected'>{{name}}</li>
<!-- or -->
<li on-click='selected(this, i)'>{{name}}</li>
{{/items}}
```

in your code

```
new Ractive({
    ...
    selected: function(item, index){
        // in lieu of passing in, you can access via this.event:
        var item = this.event.context // current array member
        var index = this.event.index.i // current index
    },
    oninit: function(){
        this.on('selected', function(){
            // same as method above
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, the arrays aren't enormous. Before I saw your answer I was doing a very similar getKeyById using jQuery.each and jumping out of the loop when the id is found. I'm assuming your way is faster... what do you think?

Comment: I was thinking it would be nice if ractive could do something like jQuery's [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like reactive.get('items[id=23]')

Comment: Where are the actions coming from that are causing you to want to get by id? If it's actions from rendered template, you should use self-referential context because you already have access to the index and the array item.

Comment: I'm using web sockets, ajax, etc. to keep data up to date. When new data comes from the server, the only way I know how to identify the data is by the id.

Comment: Ah yes, then that's makes sense. Should be performant if they array size isn't too big. Otherwise you could create a hash by id.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm actually not using findIndex because it's so new still and not fully supported, but I'm marking your answer as accepted because it's so complete. I'll add my jQuery version as another answer just in case anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, it can be done like this:

```
Ractive.prototype.getKeyById = function(keypath, id) {
  var key;
  key = -1;
  $.each(this.get(keypath), function(i, data) {
    if (data.id === id) {
      key = i;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return key;
};
```